# C# Using Reshacker to change executable's Icon

Tags: c#, icons, clone

There are MULTIPLE threads here asking how to change an icon - and nearly all of them say to use a command line tool such as ResHacker - but none of them (that I have seen) explain how to do so. I read into ResHacker's help file, and I found some text which explained how to go about changing the icon of a win32 executable file.

I tried the below code, and it gave me the following error:
Code:

p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-addoverwrite " + txtProtect.Text + "," + txtProtect.Text + "," + sICOpath + "," + "ICONGROUP" + ", MAINICON, 0";

Error:

"C:\Users\Evan\Desktop\ResHacker.exe" -addoverwrite C:\Users\Evan\Desktop\output.exe,C:\Users\FARINA_EVAN\Desktop\output.exe,C:\Users\Evan\Desktop\ExeWithIcon.exe,ICONGROUP, MAINICON, 0

Error: Invalid resource type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to find anything on how to programmatically run ResHacker except through manipulating the command line through C# like you are attempting to do.  However, to speak to the root of your question, I found a possible solution for you here that does not require ResHacker.  Instead, it allows you to modify the icon through code (C# and VB.NET).  Here is the link:

http://www.hackforums.net/archive/index.php/thread-422072-1.html

Answer (score 2):

I realize that this is a bit... Old, but the reason this won't work is because you're trying to get the icon FROM a .exe, which doesn't work with the command line of ResHacker.

The only thing I can think of is to Extract the icon from the .exe and save it as a .ico.

Then you can do the "push."